# Why desktop version shown rather than responsive version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I've used bootstrap 3 in my design to make it responsive. but why does desktop version shown rather than responsive version in mobile/tablet browsers?

Here is my page:
https://payment24.ir/order-physical-visa-master-card/

Is it because of

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0;user-scalable=1;">
```

or not? what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```